# Help in finding $\int \frac{x+x\sin x+e^x \cos x}{e^x+x\cos x-e^{x} \sin x} dx$

Tags: integration

I want to find
$$\int \frac{x+x\sin x+e^x \cos x}{e^x+x\cos x-e^{x} \sin x} dx.$$
But since algebraic, exponential and trigonometric functions are involved I am not able to solve it. Please help in finding it by hand.

Comment: [Wolframalpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bx%5Csin+x%2Be%5Ex+%5Ccos+x%7D%7Be%5Ex%2Bx%5Ccos+x-e%5E%7Bx%7D+%5Csin+x%7D+dx.)

Comment: But how to get it by hand.

Comment: Wow, nice @ArcticChar. How might one notice / spot the substitution? Seems hard...

Comment: Dharmendra Singh, nice profile! Would you mind joining us here https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1508/general-chatroom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the law of equal peopoetions, we have: $$\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin x} \implies \frac{x(1+\sin x)}{x \cos x}=\frac{e^x \cos x}{e^x-e^x \sin x}=\frac{x+x\sin x+e^x \cos x}{x\cos x+ e^{x}-e^{x} \sin x}$$
So $$\int \frac{x+x\sin x+e^x \cos x}{e^x+x\cos x-e^{x} \sin x} dx= \int \frac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}dx=-\ln (1-\sin x)+C$$

Comment: +1 I believe this is more commonly known as [componendo and dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/).

Comment: How did you get the last equality on the first line?

Comment: It's because if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ (and $b+d\ne0$), then $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For $1+\sin x\ne0,$

the denominator

$$=e^x(1-\sin x)+x\cos x$$

$$=\dfrac{e^x\cos^2x+x\cos x(1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x}$$

$$=\dfrac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\cdot (e^x\cos x+x(1+\sin x))$$

Can you recognize the numerator as a multiplicand?